# Interplay between the art of integration and differential equations

Tags: integration

Is there any interplay between "integration theory", if you will, and the theory of differential equations? And if so how exactly is the connection? To be precise, let's take as an example this: $$\int f'(g(x))g'(x)\,dx=f(g(x))+C,$$ this is true since all functions $f,g\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy the differential equation $f'(g(x))g'(x)=(f(g(x)))'$. The essence of my question is can differential equations be used to find the solutions of integrals.

I know that there's this field called differential Galois theory from which it can be proved that certain functions have no antiderivative in terms of elementary functions, but can it help in the pursuit of solutions of integrals? I also know that the Laplace transform can be used to find integrals which is what prompted my question initially.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but there is a technique, referred to as differentiation under the integral sign, in which you insert a parameter in an integral, differentiate with respect to that parameter (any number of times), and solve the resulting differential equation. Often, the parameter is inserted in such a way that differentiating with respect to it makes the integral easier to compute.

Comment: @Zachary right, my question is is there some field that puts all of the Feynman trick, laplace transform, ..etc into a coherent structure.

Comment: @Zachary here's a perfect example of what I have in mind: https://www.unf.edu/~dbell/Poisson.pdf